# Load Screen - iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I know you can place an image and name it "Default.png" to show a default load screen, but what if you want to add a UIActivityIndicator for example to show some graphical display whilst the application is loading..?

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a loading graphical display show up right when the application starts up. The closest that you can get is to set the background image of the very first view in your application to the same Default.png graphic and put a `UIActivityIndicator` somewhere in that view. This would give you a seamless transition between the start-up image and the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is often accomplished by having a load screen in `Default.png (which is actually often only ever seen for a very short moment), and the replacing this with a new, shiny animated version as your first view controller.