# UIActivityIndicator while app is starting up

Tags: iphone, startup, launch, uiactivityindicatorview

I have searched but not found exactly what I was looking for. I have a UITabBar application that, in the first view, loads a large set of data from the web. This might take several seconds, especially when connected to an Edge network.

I have a startup screen showing a logo etc., but I would like to add an activity indicator to show the user that something is actually going on.

How can I achieve this? The posts I have found do only regard ActivityIndicators while switching between tabs.

Thanks

Comment: Uhh, just load and display it in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method of your main view controller?

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, onnoweb, but I am unable to make the UIActivityIndicator appear on top of my Default.png image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783903/load-screen-iphone-app/6783966

Comment: j0k: thanks for the link, I have searched but not found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loading of data takes much time you can take another view controller as your rootViewController just having the Splashscreen (The screen having the image or view that you can display till the data is being downloaded) and activity indicator and when your download completes remove the temprootViewcontroller from the window and add your original controller to the window.

**Edit**

```
    //To show custom Splash screen do something like in
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

SplashScreenVC *splashScreenVC = [[SplashScreenVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenVC" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = splashScreenVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//And when your data finishes downloading you can write following there to show your tabBar.

AppDelegate*delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
delegate.window.rootViewController = delegate.tabBarController;
[delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//If you want to simulate downloading and want to sleep the device you can try this in SplashScreenVC

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [self performSelector:@selector(gotosleep) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
    -(void)gotosleep{
        sleep(5);
        AppDelegate*delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        delegate.window.rootViewController = delegate.tabBarController;
        [delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Comment: This sounds as the solution for me. But I just want to clearify something. My app is a tabbar app, does this mean that my rootViewController is the viewController of the first view in the tabbar?

Comment: in applicationDidFinishLaunching you might find something like `[window addSubview:tabbar.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];` You just need to cut this code and addSubview your tempview.view in the window and when finished downloading remove it from superview. and then paste the code and you are done.

Comment: I have a bit of trouble getting this to work. In my AppDelegate.m I have the following line (which I assume are the line you talk about above): self.window.rootViewController = loadScreen; This does indeed change the view  to the view of loadScreen. In loadScreen's viewDidLoad I start a uiactivity indicator and simulates a huge download by adding: sleep(5). But then my view is first visible when the 5 seconds have passed...

Comment: here you when you can try calling sleep after some delay.i.e. `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self performSelector:@selector(gotosleep) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
-(void)gotosleep{
 sleep(5);
}`

Comment: I am sorry, Himanshu, but I think I have complete lost it here. Would you mind creating a small illustration?